# Reload Array and add random Value Again to View

Tags: objective-c, xcode, view

i create an array and array creating random value. And writing to labels. i added NSTimer but can not reload again value. i want to reload data with timer.How can i do that;
My Codes at below

```
 NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random() % 100 * -1],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random() %(100) * -1],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random() %(100) * -1],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random() %(100)],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random() %(100)],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random() %(100)],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random() %(100)],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random() %(100)],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random() %(100)],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random() %(100)],nil];


NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5.0
                                                      target: self
                                                    selector:@selector(selectorSwitcher:)
                                                    userInfo: nil repeats:YES];



-(void)selectorSwitcher:(NSTimer *)timer {

    [array removeAllObjects];

    //Label
    lblNumber.text= nil;


    [createview setNeedsDisplay];
    [myView setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this in a UITableView's data source, or in a UITableViewController, what you need is probably something like:

`[self.tableView reloadData];`